# Toolbar and BoxLayout overlay

Tags: python, qt

This is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 

def prova():
    print "test event"


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)                                              

    self.resize(350, 250) # ridimensiona la finestra
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')


    pause = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("icons/pause.gif"),"Pause",self)
    pause.setStatusTip("Pause!!")
    pause.triggered.connect(prova);

    play = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("icons/play.png"),"Play",self)
        play.setStatusTip("Start!")     

    toolbar = self.addToolBar('My toolbar')
    toolbar.addAction(pause)
    toolbar.addAction(play)
    toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)

    widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
    hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(widget)

    label = QtGui.QLabel()
    label.setText("test label") 
    hbox.addWidget(label)
    hbox.setAlignment(label,QtCore.Qt.Alignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My problem is that the horizontal box hbox and the widget inside, are overlayed on the toolbar. How do i fix the overlay, putting the hbox below the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding `widget` directly as child of `main` instead of setting it as central widget. So instead of:

```
widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
```

use:

```
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```